# Why does my branch think changes from master are "old"?

Tags: git

**Background**

We use a basic feature-branch workflow.  Feature branches are created from master, updated with merges from master periodically during their existence, then merged back into master after a pull request.

**Problem**

One of our current branches has gotten into a state in which git appears to consider the contents of the branch to always be newer than what is in master.  Some examples:

- If we merge master into the branch, any files which are new to master (added after the branch was created) are ignored; they are not added to the branch during the merge.  My assumption is that git is treating them as if they were deliberately deleted on the branch.
- There are several files which have been modified in master since the branch was created.  The Bitbucket pull request shows the reverse of these changes as pending changes to master when the PR is merged.  For example, let's say a line was changed in master from

```
myConstant = 26
```

to

```
myConstant = 27
```

After merging master into the branch, the PR shows that merging [the branch back into master] will change `27` [back] to `26`.

*Note: this was a fairly long-running feature branch, and it had several "sub-feature-branches" come from it.  At least one was merged back in.  Another still exists and has had updates merged from master to feature-branch, then from feature-branch to sub-feature-branch.*

**How to fix?**

I'm not sure exactly how we got into this predicament.  I'm sifting through a few months worth of commits, and I see a few, possibly-ill-advised merges that may have done it.  Merging from master to sub-feature-branch to feature-branch, for example.  However, I haven't found one yet with a huge file list on it.  If anyone has a more concrete idea of what types of actions get you into this situation, I would love to hear those.

Even if I find the smoking gun, I'm not sure which is the best way to remedy the situation.  My current thought is overwriting (checkout from master) any files which we know were not changed explicitly in the branch.  Obviously, the branch also has changes which *are* newer than master, so even that is tedious & risky.  Suggestions welcome :)

**Update 1**

After more digging & using some of the tools from @torek's excellent answer, I have found the problem commit - or at least one of them.  The commit graph looks something like this (I used numbers to avoid confusion with the letters from earlier discussion.  `X`s represent one or more non-merge commits.  Master is at the bottom; I have not noted individual commits there.):

```
                                                                               X-------57-X--------61-X--------62--65
                                                                              /        /           /            \   \
                                                                           51-55-X-56- / -X-67-----73-------------63--66-71
                                                                          /       /  /     /      /                     /
    34-35-X----37-X-X-38-X-X-39------41-X-----42-X-----44-X-46---47-X-50-X-53---54--------60-----68                    /  
    /          /      /      /       / \      /        /        /    /          /                /                    /
32-33----36-X-X----- / ---- / ---X-40   ---- / --43-X---X---45-48-X-49-52---------58------------59-------69---72     /
/        /          /      /       /        /               /       /  /          /              \       /    /     /
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       70--- / -- / -----
                                                                                           \      /    /    /
                                                                                            ----------------
```

Commit `39` turns out to be the problem.  The committer appears to have started a merge, cleared out all of the pending changes (without aborting the merge), made a single file change, then committed.  A comparison to the parent commit coming from `38` shows only the single file change.  However, a comparison to the parent commit from master shows a laundry list of unintended changes.

I am now to the "what to do about it" phase.  I'm digging into options including altering commit `39` itself, making a new commit starting from `71` to reverse the changes in `39`, etc.

**Update 2**

After doing some reading, it seems most people are recommending the same set of things - outlined pretty well [here](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#pushed_new_merge).  My current thinking is that rebasing that far back, with a bunch of merges since, could get ugly (though my rebase Kung Fu is not strong), so I'm inclined to go with the revert approach (`git revert -m 2 <Commit_39_SHA>`).  Bisect was already pretty well broken on these branches anyway.

The plan is to merge all of the sub-feature branches into the main feature branch and run the revert there.  If I'm understanding everything correctly, I don't think I'll need the "revert the revert" step.

Comment: The "what to do about it" phase is always tricky!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's never a question of *age*.  For merging, it's always a matter of *merge bases*.

Every commit has a parent, or in the case of merge commits, two or more parents.  The true name of each commit is its hash ID—the big ugly string of letters and digits such as `83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6`.  That true name lets Git find the actual commit.  The commit itself stores the hash ID of its parent(s), which lets Git find *those* commits.  They store the hash IDs of their parents in turn, and so on.  The result is that for most commits, there's a simple linear backwards chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is some commit hash ID, and `H`'s parent is `G`, whose parent is `F`, and so on.

This backwards-pointing chain, which is mostly linear, *is* the history.  History in Git is just a series of commits.  A branch name like `master` simply holds *one* hash ID: the ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  So we can draw the above as:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Each commit has a full and complete snapshot of all files—well, all files as of the time you made the commit, because once made, every commit is frozen in time.

Branches occur because two different commits have a single common commit as their (shared) parent:

```
             I--J   <-- branch1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- branch2
```

Git will start at each tip commit—`J` and `L`, in this case—and work backwards.  When starting from both branches and working backwards, the two branches arrive at their shared common commit `H`.

If you pick one branch to `git checkout`, you get that one commit:

```
             I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- branch2
```

Git has attached `HEAD` to the name `branch1`, which means commit `J` is the commit you have checked out: `branch1` identifies commit `J`.

Now you run `git merge branch2`.  Git finds commit `L`, because the name `branch2` points to `L`.  From `J` and `L`, Git works backwards, one commit at a time, to find the shared commit `H`.  That's the *merge base*.

Git now compares the snapshot in `H`—the one that you, on `branch1`, started from—with the snapshot in `J`, that you probably also made, and are on now.  Whatever is *different* here, that's what *you* changed.  If you *did* change `myConstant = 26` to `myConstant = 27`, that's your change, to that particular file.  If you *didn't* change `myConstant` at all, you made *no* change.

Git also compares the snapshot in `H`—which is the best one that they, on `branch2`, started from that you also started from (commits `F` and `G` would work too but they're obviously not as good)—to their commit `L`, to see what *they* changed.

Having done the comparison from `H` to `J` and again from `H` to `L`, Git now knows what *you* changed, and what *they* changed.  It doesn't matter *when* you changed things, or *when* they changed things.  All that matters is whether *someone* changed something.  In any case, Git extracts all the files from `H` (not `J` nor `L`), applies *both sets of changes* to them, and—if there are no conflicts—commits the result:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- branch2
```

Because you're on `branch1`, the new commit `M` goes on `branch1`.  Because it's the *last* commit, Git updates the name `branch1` to identify commit `M`.  Meanwhile, though, commit `M` has not one but *two* parent commits: `J`, your previous tip, and `L`, which is still their branch tip.

Now suppose that both you *and* they made some change to `myConstant`.  Then, when trying to combine your two changes, Git will have declared a *merge conflict*.  It will have left a mess in the work-tree (and the index) for whoever was running `git merge` to fix.  It's then up to the *human* to figure out what to put into commit `M`, by editing the conflicted files and fixing that line.  Whatever the human puts in, Git assumes that this is the *correct* result.  Let's say the human picks 26 instead of 27, and commits that.  Commit `M` now says `myConstant = 26`, and *Git is sure that this is correct*, even if it's not.  Or, we can say that the human picks 27 instead of 26, and commits that; now Git is sure that 27 is correct.

Suppose you and they go on to make more commits:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M--N--O   <-- branch1
            \    /
             K--L--P--Q--R   <-- branch2
```

If you now pick one of these branches to check out, you'll get either commit `O` or commit `R`.  Let's say you pick `O` and run `git merge branch2` again.

Git now starts at `O` and works backwards: `O`, `N`, `M`, both-`J`-and-`L` ....  And it starts at `R` and works backwards: `R`, `Q`, `P`, `L`, ....  Note that these both arrive at commit `L`.  Commit `L` is the merge base—not `M`, `L`.  So Git will diff `M` against `O` to see what you changed.  That might include changing 26 to 27, or—if `M` itself has the wrong constant—doing nothing at all.  Then it compares `L` to `R`, to see what they changed.

As before, Git combines these changes, and if both you and they touched the same lines of the same file, you get a merge conflict.  You clean it up and make the merge commit yourself.  If not, and Git combines everything on its own successfully, Git makes a merge commit immediately.  Either way you now have:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M--N--O--S   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \    /        /
             K--L--P--Q--R   <-- branch2
```

where `S` is your merge result.  The constant in that file is set however you, or Git, set it, based on whether there was a conflict and/or whether you and/or they made any change to that line when comparing `L` (the merge base) with `O` and `R` (the two sides of the merge).

#### Finding who changed something is easy, except when it's hard

Git has some tools by which you can try to find out who set `myConstant` to whatever value.  The two big ones are `git log` and `git blame`.  Both start at some commit, to see what's in that commit, then work backwards, one commit at a time.  By comparing what's in the *parent* commit to what's in the *child*, Git can see if, say, commits `N` and `O` have different lines there.  If so, Git can tell you that whoever made `O` changed that line.

But when Git is working backwards through a merge like `S` or `M`, *which parent should Git compare to `S`?*  Git's answers (plural) to this are quite tricky.  Some commands just don't bother comparing at all—that's what `git log -p` does, for instance.  Others pick one parent and continue down that leg of the merge, i.e., starting from `S`, go back to only `R`, or only `O`.  A few, such as `git show`, can show you a *combined diff*, which in general only shows you where there was a merge conflict (combined diffs omit all files that did not have contributions from both "sides").

Since this sort of problem is often introduced at merge conflicts, combined diffs are often somewhat useful for finding where it came from.  That's not necessarily *very* useful though: it's more useful to use `git bisect` to find good and bad commits automatically.  You declare one commit "good" (where the code works / is right) and a later commit "bad" (where the code fails / is wrong), and have Git automatically search back and forth between those two commits, dealing with branch-and-merge structures within the commit graph, all automatically.

It's also sometimes useful to use `git log -m -p`.  What that does is to *split* each merge.  Instead of treating `S` and `M` as one commit each, it pretends, for the purpose of `git diff`-ing to produce the patch, that there's one `S1` commit with parent `O` and a second `S2` commit with parent `R`.  Then, upon reaching `M`, it pretends there's one `M1` commit with parent `J`, and a second `M2` commit with parent `L`.  Each of these split commits gets a simple, ordinary, *non*-combined diff against its (now lone) parent, showing you how the merge result differs from that one parent.

All of these are useful tools to see what happened.  They won't prevent mis-merges in the future, though: all Git can do is compare the base against the two tips, to see what you changed vs what they changed.  It doesn't matter *when:* only *what changed* matters.

Edit: Formatting